# Specifying seasonality in a grouped ARIMA model with fable

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm using Rob Hyndman's groovy new tidyverts family of packages (the replacement for forecast). I was just wondering how you'd specify that the data is seasonal, especially in the presence of groups.

Here's a concrete example: the orange juice data from the bayesm package. This contains sales data over time, for each combination of store and brand. Let's read it in.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(feast)
library(fable)

data(orangeJuice, package="bayesm")
yx <- orangeJuice$yx

# data doesn't have every week represented, so fill in the gaps
fill_oj_data <- function()
{
    stores <- unique(yx$store)
    brands <- unique(yx$brand)
    grid <- expand.grid(store=stores, brand=brands, week=seq(min(yx$week), max(yx$week)))
    yx %>%
        full_join(grid, by=c("store", "brand", "week")) %>%
        group_by(store, brand) %>%
        arrange(week) %>%
        mutate(week=as.Date("1989-09-14") + week*7) %>%
        fill(everything())
}
oj_data <- fill_oj_data()
```

This dataset is weekly, so there should be seasonality with a period of 52. At the moment, I'm doing this to represent the seasonality:

```
oj_ts <- as_tsibble(oj_data, key=c(store, brand))

# turn the logmove variable into a ts object
oj_ts$logmove <- as.ts(oj_ts$logmove, frequency=52)

model(oj_ts, ARIMA(logmove ~ pdq() + PDQ()))
```

Is this the right way of doing it? Will `ARIMA` correctly take into account the grouped structure in fitting the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set up your index as a week variable. The following code will do what you need.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(fable)

data(orangeJuice, package="bayesm")
oj_ts <- orangeJuice$yx %>%
  mutate(
    week = yearweek(as.Date("1989-09-14") + week*7)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=week, key=c(store,brand)) %>%
  fill_gaps() %>%
  fill(logmove, .direction="down")
```

You should not use `ts` objects. A `tsibble` contains the time information. Here, because week is of class `week`, the `ARIMA` function will know about its seasonality.

All you need is to fit the models like this.

```
fit <- oj_ts %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(logmove))
```

This will fit an ARIMA model for every combination of `brand` and `store`. Some combinations of `brand` and `store` do not have enough data to fit a model, and in those cases a NULL model is returned.

You do not actually need to interpolate the data using `fill()` here. The ARIMA model will handle missing data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Rob. I should also mention, `fill` isn't even doing interpolation; it's just extending the last non-missing value forwards. This doesn't strike me as very smart, but I wasn't aware of any alternatives; if ARIMA will do a better job on its own, that's great.